# Como pasar 2 parametros en asp.net mvc desde un dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net

Estoy intentando pasar 2 parametros al metodo que se encuentra en el controlador desde la vista, pero solo me reconoce el valor del primer parametro, el otro llega como null, que estoy haciendo mal, este es el codigo.

Vista

```
table>
        <tr>
           <% foreach (var item2 in Model)
                { %>
                    <input type="hidden" id="idColegio" value="<%: item2.idColegio %>"  />
                <td><p style="color:black;font-size:medium">Gestiones:</p></td>
                <td><%: Html.DropDownList("gest", new SelectList(ViewBag.gestiones, "Value", "Text"), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", onchange = "document.location.href = '/CursosOfrecidos/Index?id='+ this.options[this.selectedIndex].value , 'idColegio='+item2.idColegio", style = "width:150px;", @id = "ges", @name = "gestion" }) %></td>                                       
        </tr>         
    </table>
```

Controlador

```
public ActionResult Index(int id, int? idColegio )
{
    return View(cursoso);
}
```

Ayuda por fa...

Answer (score 0):

Los parámetros en el QueryString de la URL no los debes separar con comas debes separarlos con ampersand y también debes ajustar algunas comillas dobles y sencillas:

```
"document.location.href = '/CursosOfrecidos/Index?id='+ this.options[this.selectedIndex].value' + '&idColegio='"+ item2.idColegio
```

Comment: Gracias por responder Weimar, hice como me dijiste pero aun tengo error, me sale este error:   Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string